# random number in while loop [C programming]

Tags: c, loops, random

I'm trying to create 2 random numbers (between 0-4 and 0-10) in each time the cycle occurs, but it always give the same number.
If I run the program multiple times, it gives different numbers, but the while cycle always generates the same 2 numbers.
thanks.

```
int random(int range){
    int num;
    srand(time(NULL));
    num = rand() % range;
    return num;
}

int main(){

    int cnt = 0;
    int i;  
    int j;
    while (cnt <= 20) {
        i = random(5);
        j = random(10);
        printf("%d\n",i);
        printf("%d\n",j);
        printf("\n");
        cnt += 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Call srand once (and only once) in main. Search, this issue comes up every week.

Comment: If you call the `srand(`) in the same millisecond you will have the same outputs, it won't be random at all. And yes the computer will process both `srand()`'s under a millisecond so the answers will be the same. The `srand()` is used to make the randomizer behave randomly from outsiders. You don't have to use `srand()` only once like people say you can use it every minute if you wish to make the results even less predictable from the public.

Comment: who voted this question up, and why?

Comment: Note that rand() is a very poor quality pseudo-random number generator in most implementations. It repeats over a fairly short period. If the quality of the random numbers matters at all, consider finding a better generator. If you're using Linux, /dev/urandom is an excellent choice.

Comment: Another quality point is that the `rand()%range` expression doesn't reliably provide a uniform distribution, particularly if `range` is large relative to the largest value of `rand()`.

Comment: and on Mac OS X you have arc4rand family and even M$ has some pretty awesome random number library support... watch this: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You only need to seed the random number generator once.

So run this line outside of your random function:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

.. in your main function instead:

```
int random(int range){
    int num;
    num = rand() % range;
    return num;
}

int main(){
    int cnt = 0;
    int i;    
    int j;

    // Seed random number generator
    srand(time(NULL));

    while (cnt <= 20){
        i = random(5);
        j = random(10);
        printf("%d\n",i);
        printf("%d\n",j);
        printf("\n");
        cnt += 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You require to seed the random function just once. Include the time.h library and use

```
#include<time.h>
.....
srand(time(NULL));
```